# Transfrom file.txt content into a df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I woul need help in order to transform a file content into a pandas dataframe.

here is the file :

```
>OK0100087.1
0 375
376 750
751 1000
>OK0100088.1
0 87766
>OK0100089.1
0 66778
>OK0100090.1
0 47519
47520 73733
```

and the idea is that I would like to change this file content in a df such as :

```
Name           start end
OK0100087.1_0  0      375
OK0100087.1_1  376    750
OK0100087.1_2  751    1000
OK0100088.1    0      87766
OK0100089.1    0      66778
OK0100090.1_0  0      47519
OK0100090.1_1  47520  73733
```

where I add a _Number if several rows after the `>OK...number`

and where start are the first number and the end the last for each line.

does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really straight forward because you need to increment the keys when there are multiple data for one (which require at least to read enought lines to either find a new `>` or and end of file.

1. Read the data stupidly
2. Then transform it into records
3. and when it's done make it a dataframe

How it could be written:

```
import pandas as pd

DATA_FILE = 'data.txt'


def read_file(filename):
    data = {}
    current_key = None
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                current_key = line.strip()[1:]
                data[current_key] = []
            elif current_key:
                data[current_key].append([int(i) for i in line.split(' ')])
    return data


def prepare_data(data):
    records = []
    for key in data:
        if len(data[key]) > 1:
            # case where a key have multiple lines (we add a suffix)
            for i, d in enumerate(data[key]):
                records.append({
                    'name': '{}_{}'.format(key, i),
                    'start': d[0],
                    'end': d[1]})
        elif len(data[key]) == 1:
            # otherwise no suffix needed
            records.append({
                'name': key,
                'start': data[key][0][0],
                'end': data[key][0][1]})
    return records


def main():
    data = read_file(DATA_FILE)
    records = prepare_data(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(records)
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your data so it's easy to load to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

records = []

with open('f.txt', 'r') as f:
    idx = None
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith('>OK'):
            idx = line.strip()[1:]
        else:
            start, end = line.strip().split()
            records.append({
                'start': start,
                'end': end,
                'Name': idx
            })

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```